# How to see the original author of a commit?

Tags: git

How can I see the original account email of a commit, if the same account use different profiles? For example my email account is `email1@email.com` and I make some commits as `email2@email.com` and `email3@email.com` by changing the `user.email` config property, how can I find the first email? The original author?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try `git log` ?

Comment: Did you change your email before or after making the commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`git show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) will show the authors email.

eg. `git show e8db01ccb4222c18b1b39p8d1252bd41ae439552` or `git show e8db01c`

Answer (score 3):

Changing the user.email *after* creating a commit won't change the author email of past commits.

`git log` or `git show` can, through a `--format:` option show you only the author name and email:

```
git show --format="%aN <%aE>" COMMIT_ID
```